# How best to horizontally align ruby on rails form text_fields?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have the following form in one of my view files, however the date of birth fields, day, month and year are staggered when it is actually rendered. That is each successive field is shown down and to the right of the preceding field. I want them to appear horizontally next to one another. It works if I do not have any form labels.

```
  <div class="date-input form-group" id="dob">
    <%= form.label :dob_day, :class =>"date-input-label" %>
    <%= form.text_field :dob_day, id: 'dob_day', :class =>"date-input-item" %>
    <%= form.label :dob_month, :class =>"date-input-label" %>
    <%= form.text_field :dob_month, id: 'dob_month', :class =>"date-input__item" %>
    <%= form.label :dob_year, :class =>"date-input-label" %>
    <%= form.text_field :dob_year, id: 'dob_year', :class =>"date-input-item" %>
  </div>
```

I have tried to put the labels and text_fields into their own tables and using CSS cell padding to try and space them appropriately but they need individual spacing to do that and not something I can just apply equally to each cell.

Am I missing something in rails that will do this for me? Or do I need to apply inline css styling to each cell to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)

Then:

`rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap`

and in your view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @someting, wrapper: :inline_form, html: { class: 'form-inline' } do |form|%>
 <%= form.input :dob_day, id: 'dob_day', :class =>"date-input-item" %>
 <%= form.input :dob_month, id: 'dob_month', :class =>"date-input__item" %>
 <%= form.input :dob_year, id: 'dob_year', :class =>"date-input-item" %>
<% end %>
```